# why I cannot get the path of css and js file

Tags: javascript, html, java-ee-6

I made a website project.
But now i meet a problem.
I cannot get the path of css and js file no matter what I do.
Just like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ckplayer/css/ckplayer.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckplayer/js/ckplayer.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

And

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ckplayer/css/ckplayer.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckplayer/js/ckplayer.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

And

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}\ckplayer\css\ckplayer.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}\ckplayer\js\ckplayer.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

What should I do?Any help would be appreciated.

The  folder structure is as follow:

1. ckplayer
   [1]: css  (1)ckplayer.css
   [2]：js   (1)ckplayer.js

2.pages
[1]:video
(1)video.jsp

Comment: What is folder structure alike ? where is standing the calling page and the CSS/JS files about ? (./ , / ../ )

Comment: I have edited it.bc i cannot paste the image so I user the text to express it.Can u understand it?

Comment: not too sure, your page is standing inside ckplayer folder ? and then css and js are subfolder, right ? if so, the path should be alike :`css/ckplayer.css` I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your second try should work based on the folder structure you are showing. Hard to say for sure.

If your page is at:

```
/pages/video/video.jsp
```

then

```
/ckplayer/css/ckplayer.css
```

looks correct as they both reference from the root.